# How to import Prisma model in prisma-offset-pagination

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, pagination, prisma2

I am using a package **prisma-offset-pagination** to apply pagination.
For this I have to use Prisma Model in my code, how is that possible:
**Check line: 02**

```
const result = prismaOffsetPagination({
    model: user,   // How to access prisma model like in this example.
    cursor: <cursor>,
    size: 5,
    buttonNum: 7,
    orderBy: 'id',
    orderDirection: 'desc',
    prisma: prisma,
});
```

I tried it using the code below but it didn't work and throws an error :
*UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
at prismaOffsetPagination*

```
import pClient from '@prisma/client'
const { PrismaClient } = pClient
const { prisma } = new PrismaClient()

  const result = prismaOffsetPagination({
    model: prisma.user,
    cursor: 2,
    size: 5,
    buttonNum: 3,
    orderBy: 'id',
    orderDirection: 'desc',
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how prismaOffsetPagination function looks like:

```
export async function prismaOffsetPagination({
  model,
  cursor,
  size,
  buttonNum,
  orderBy,
  orderDirection,
  include,
  where,
  prisma,
}: Props<typeof model>): Promise<PaginationType> {
  // totalCount
  const prismaModel = prisma[model.name.toLowerCase()];
  const totalCount = await prismaModel.count({
    where: {
      ...where,
    },
  });
```

As you can see, `model.name.toLowerCase()` suggests that model is an object with a name property: `model:{name:string}`

Based on this, for me it worked passing the name of the model inside the object, as follows:

```
const result = prismaOffsetPagination({
    model: {name: 'user'}
    cursor: <cursor>,
    size: 5,
    buttonNum: 7,
    orderBy: 'id',
    orderDirection: 'desc',
    prisma: prisma,
});
```